# Where can I find a list and documentation for samba share definitions?

Tags: samba

I'm looking for a reference for what goes under the share name... I feel like there are about 6 dozen different options but I can't find a good reference anywhere... someone help me out?

```
[myshare]
    path = /export/myshare
    valid users = mydomain\user1 mydomain\user2
    public = no
    writable = yes
    browseable = No
```

Comment: Almost all options but a few can be placed under a share name. The _global_ section is for setting defaults for all shares. There is official [documentation](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/) and a complete reference in the manual pages. It would be more appropriate to ask how to solve a specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

The [smb.conf(5)](http://samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html) man page covers this.  It lists all the parameters and says

> The letter G in parentheses indicates that a parameter is specific to the [global] section. The letter S indicates that a parameter can be specified in a service specific section. All S parameters can also be specified in the [global] section - in which case they will define the default behavior for all services.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [SWAT](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/SWAT.html)?

It is started from `xinetd`. Have a look for something like `/etc/xinetd.d/swat` and set `disabled = no`, then restart `xinetd`.  This does assume that you have `xinetd` installed and SWAT is included with your Samba.  Also you may want to change the only from line to `0.0.0.0` for remote access.  Disable it again after use ...

You should be able to point your browser at `http://localhost:901` and then login.  You may want to run `#smbpasswd -a root` to add an account that can can edit **smb.conf.**

The docs are all linked into SWAT including an HTML version of the man page.